# Remove the collapse/expand function if the parent element doesn't have child

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, tree

I'm using the Nestable code (https://dbushell.com/Nestable/). In the list, the user can drag and drop the items until level 2. Basically, the item can have a father, in maximum.

If the item has child, this item show the expand and collapse functions. When the item does not have child, this item doesn't show the expand and collapse functions.

And I have created a function to remove items.

So, when I delete the child item and the parent item doesn't have any child, the collapse and expand functions don't disappear. These functions should be disappear.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marcelpsaraiva/8p3ntu91/)

[image]
[image]

The code:

```
<div class="dd" id="nestable">
            <ol class="dd-list outer">
                <li class="dd-item" data-id="1">
                    <button class='dd-action pull-right' type='button' data-action='remove' title='Remove'><i class='icon-remove'></i></button>
                    <div class="dd-handle">Item 1</div>
                </li>
                <li class="dd-item" data-id="2">
                    <button class='dd-action pull-right' type='button' data-action='remove' title='Remove'><i class='icon-remove'></i></button>
                    <div class="dd-handle">Item 2</div>
                    <ol class="dd-list">
                        <li class="dd-item" data-id="4">
                            <button class='dd-action pull-right' type='button' data-action='remove' title='Remove'><i class='icon-remove'></i></button>
                            <div class="dd-handle">Item 4</div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dd-item" data-id="9">
                            <button class='dd-action pull-right' type='button' data-action='remove' title='Remove'><i class='icon-remove'></i></button>
                            <div class="dd-handle">Item 9</div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dd-item" data-id="10">
                            <button class='dd-action pull-right' type='button' data-action='remove' title='Remove'><i class='icon-remove'></i></button>
                            <div class="dd-handle">Item 10</div>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
                <li class="dd-item" data-id="11">
                    <button class='dd-action pull-right' type='button' data-action='remove' title='Remove'><i class='icon-remove'></i></button>
                    <div class="dd-handle">Item 11</div>
                </li>
                <li class="dd-item" data-id="12">
                    <button class='dd-action pull-right' type='button' data-action='remove' title='Remove'><i class='icon-remove'></i></button>
                    <div class="dd-handle">Item 12</div>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    var updateOutput = function(e)
    {
        var list   = e.length ? e : $(e.target),
            output = list.data('output');
        if (window.JSON) {
            output.val(window.JSON.stringify(list.nestable('serialize')));
        } else {
            output.val('JSON browser support required for this demo.');
        }
    };

    // activate Nestable for list 1
    $('#nestable').nestable({
        group: 1,
        expandBtnHTML   : '<button class="dd-action" data-action="expand" type="button"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></button>',
        collapseBtnHTML : '<button class="dd-action" data-action="collapse" type="button"><i class="icon-chevron-down"></i></button>',
        customActions   : {
            'remove'    : function(item,button) {
                            item.remove();
                        }
        }
    })
    .on('change', updateOutput);

    // output initial serialised data
    updateOutput($('#nestable').data('output', $('#nestable-output')));

    $('#nestable-menu').on('click', function(e)
    {
        var target = $(e.target),
            action = target.data('action');
        if (action === 'expand-all') {
            $('.dd').nestable('expandAll');
        }
        if (action === 'collapse-all') {
            $('.dd').nestable('collapseAll');
        }
    });

});
```